# How to instantiate a Lead object based on a Saved Lead?

Tags: leads

To the stars,

I am trying to do the following:

Using Apex,

1. Instantiate a Lead Object based on an existing Lead in the database
2. Use that lead object to generate JSON data to be used in a callout

My first challenge is to instantiate the Lead Object based on a Saved Lead. How would I do that?

Thanks very much,
EC

Comment: I meant to state that I have the Lead object on the Salesforce UI screen. I want the Apex code to instantiate an object based on the Lead selected and being viewed in the UI.

Comment: Have you gone through the trailhead trails and modules I suggested in your previous question? They should go a fair way towards getting you to a solution here.

Comment: Yes, I have covered those trailhead topics. I don't see any discussion or topic related to exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Instantiate a Lead Object based on an existing Lead in the database**
   Given your comment, I think you can simply use "Clone" in the Salesforce UI, the lead record detail page. [image]
2. **Use that lead object to generate JSON data to be used in a callout**
   You can use this JSON class to convert something to JSON format data.
   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Json.htm

As Derek mentioned in your previous question, I also suggest you see the trailhead modules first. It would be a big help for you to get insights.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding instantiating the Lead in Apex, if you need values from several fields in an existing record, you should get it from a SOQL query.  If you do not need values that are currently in the record but you know the ID, you can simply instantiate with new, optionally setting additional fields.

```
Id leadId = '00Q00000000000012345';

Lead sfLead = [ SELECT Id, Name, ... 
                FROM Lead
                WHERE Id = :leadId ];

// or     

Lead sfLead = new Lead (Id = leadId, Name = 'Something', ...);
```

Comment: That is very close to what I need. I have a Lead in focus on the screen.  How do I populate the Id leadId = currentllySelectedLead.Id

Comment: You mention "Lead Object based on a Saved Lead. "  Is the Lead saved via the regular SF UI and you need to do backend processing based on the Lead that was?  If so, the solution is simply to use Apex Triggers on the Lead object.  Be advised that there are several considerations when writing triggers such as bulkifying all queries/DMLs and you will not be able to make callouts directly; you will have to use @future or Queueable to spawn an async process.